# How to relabel genes in excel according to their probe?

Tags: excel, conditional-statements

I have a list of 61005 probes in an excel spreadsheet. They are all labelled with the gene they are from, and so I have a gene ID column as shown below.

As you can see there are often various probes for the same gene. How can I label these genes so that they can be recognisable from just the gene name, not the probe.

For example for Gene ending in 100009, there are two probes and I want to label them as follows:

GENE:JGI_V11_1000090102 - adding an 01 to indicate first probe, and 02 to indicate out of two probes
GENE:JGI_V11_1000090202 - adding 0202 to indicate probe 2 out of 2

```
GENE_ID
GENE:JGI_V11_100009
GENE:JGI_V11_100009
GENE:JGI_V11_100036
GENE:JGI_V11_100036
GENE:JGI_V11_100036
GENE:JGI_V11_100044
GENE:JGI_V11_100045
GENE:JGI_V11_100062
GENE:JGI_V11_100062
GENE:JGI_V11_100066
GENE:JGI_V11_100066
GENE:JGI_V11_100066
```

can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: It is possible. Clue: use `COUNTIF` formula.

Comment: Thank you. How do I use this to relabel, I have tried but it just gives me a result of 0?

Comment: With formula you can't relabel but build the output in another column. Can you show us the formula you've tried?

Comment: Unfortunately I've deleted it and not sure what I wrote. I am a complete beginner using excel for anything non-basic so I don't even know where to start in order to rebuild them in another column.

Comment: Assuming that data begins in cell A2 and goes downwards you can try formula like `=CONCATENATE(A2,TEXT(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2),"00"),TEXT(COUNTIF(A:A,A2),"00"))` and copy down as much needed.

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much, thats perfect!